# Aplicación de gestor de tareas con Angular

Tags: angular

Para practicar Angular estoy haciendo un tablón de tareas que va a mostrar las tareas según dos estados, pendiente y realizado.
Al principio era capaz de añadir tareas y visualizarlas cuando usaba un tipo sencillo de dato que era un string. Pero luego quise hacer el tipo de dato más complejo y capturar dos cosas: el nombre de la tarea y estado. Para ello declaro una interface.
Ahora no consigo mostrar elementos en el tablón.

Aquí está el código de `app.component.html`:

```
<h1>Tasks Manager</h1>
<input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="newTask.name" />
<button (click)="addTask()">Add task</button>
<ul>
  <li *ngIf="tasks.length === 0">There aren´t tasks</li>
  <h2>Tasks List</h2>
  <li *ngFor="let task of tasks; index as i">
    {{ i + 1 }} {{ task.name }}
    <button (click)="deleteTask(i)">Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Aquí el código de app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

enum States {pending,done }

interface Task {
  name : string;
  state: States;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})


export class AppComponent {
   tasks: Task[];
   newTask :Task;


  addTask() {
    this.tasks.push(this.newTask);
  }

  deleteTask(index: number) {
    this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
  }
 
     
}
```

Puede accederse al proyecto en:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fugf4j?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Y verse desplegado en:
https://angular-ivy-fugf4j.stackblitz.io

Comment: Como los errores dicen `cannot read properties of undefined`. Has declarado las variables `task` y `tasks` pero nunca las has *inicializado*... por lo tanto, son `undefined`. Te recomiendo que si quieres usar variables en la vista, las inicialices primero o compruebes que están inicializadas antes de intentar pintar el objeto que representan. Por ejemplo, `newTask= {} as Task;`, `tasks = [] as Task[]`. El error que obtienes, es lo que en Java se llama NullPointerException, estás intentando acceder a variables de un objeto que es `null` (o undefined en este caso, tanto da)!